# SQL Injection in FORM Authentication pages

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

```
SELECT *
FROM admin_table
WHERE username = '' OR '1'='1' AND password = '';

SELECT *
FROM admin_table
WHERE username = '' OR 1=1 OR '1'='1' AND password = '';
```

How do the above two SQL statements get interpreted by SQL Server?

What are the scenarios the `WHERE` clause is always True?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `WHERE` is true if `username` is blank, or ( 1=1 (ie. true) and `password` is blank), so either one has to be blank
2. `WHERE` is true if `username` is blank, or 1=1, or ( 1=1 and `password` is blank) so always true.

The real solution is **NOT** to try and outsmart SQL injection by sanitizing or writing odd queries. The solution is to separate code and data. Code is executed, data is not. Therefore, **always** parameterize your queries.

---

In my personal opinion, the biggest issue facing SQL as a language is that it encourages ad-hoc interpreted scripts that mix code with data absolutely everywhere.

If code had to be compiled fully **before** it got anywhere near the DB, injection would not be such an issue.

Comment: Your final paragraph can not be emphasized strongly enough. And of course password should not be stored in plain text, with the stored password hash being compared with the computed hash from user input

Comment: @JonP I have been on SO today and answered or commented on 6 different questions that had this exact issue, most of whom were complaining about syntax errors which would have been avoided with params.